# SQL Server : Query criteria - need to extract date from datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I can't for the life of me get this to work. I've tried just about every example I've seen on here and all over the internet. I'm trying to query based on a month's worth of data. The data in the view I'm querying is in this format:

```
2012-03-20 00:00:00.000
```

Using the following criteria it's bringing back all of the dates (or nearly all of them). Any ideas?

```
AND cast(convert(varchar(10), lag.postingdate, 112) as datetime) between '2015-01-01' and '2015-01-31'
```

Original Query:

```
SELECT 
    prov.pgrp_id AS PERFORMING_PROV_ID
    , prov.pgrp_prov_name AS PERFORMING_PROV_NAME
    , lag.chgno AS CHARGE_NUM
    , lag/countcharges AS LAGTIME
    , lag.chgamt
    , lag.postingdate
FROM 
    dbo.Providers prov
RIGHT JOIN 
    dbo.LagTime_Charges_Calcs lag ON prov.pgrp_prov_cd = lag.provcode 
                                  AND prov.pgrp_practice = lag.px 
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.PlaceofService_union_v pos ON lag.px = pos.px 
                                   AND lag.poscode = pos.poscode
WHERE 
    pos.posid = '1' 
    OR pos.posid = '2' 
    AND prov.Laginclude = 'y'
    AND MONTH(lag.postingdate) = 1
    AND YEAR(lag.postingdate) = 2015 

    --and lag.postingdate between '2015-01-01 00:00:00.000' and '2015-01-31 23:59:59.000'
    --AND cast(convert(varchar(10),lag.postingdate,112) as datetime) between '2015-      01-01' and '2015-01-31'
```

Comment: Why are you converting to a string? Try `WHERE lag.postingdate >= '20150101' AND lag.postingdate < '20150201';`. Please read [this post](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mishandling-date-range-queries.aspx) and [this post](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx).

Comment: Also, stop talking about "format" - what is the actual *data type*? Does the view render that output because it is formatting the date/time value as a string for some reason? If so, stop doing that...

Comment: The above example does not work for me. The datatype of this column is (datetime, null)

Comment: It's parentheses. Put parens around your OR'd conditions.

Comment: I think you'd be also be wise to swap the first two tables and convert that to a regular left outer join. A right join just throws people off.

Comment: @shawnt00 Yes, or just `pos.posid IN ('1', '2')`.

Comment: agreed... I'm trying to get this out of an access query someone wrote and will definitely clean it up.

Comment: Makes sense it was created with a graphical query builder.

Comment: @aaron I had noted that in my answer. Somehow I'm getting the impression that the true answer got overlooked in all the other fury.

Comment: @shawnt00 Your answer appeared after I left that comment, sorry.

Comment: @aaron Thanks, I realized that. I was kind of commented on the accepted answer and all.

Comment: @shawnt00 I agree the true answer has been overlooked. Though your answer is kind of a pro+con to me - yes you highlight the actual problem (the OP may still have not recognized that), but your non-sargable method guarantees at best a tie for the worst possible performance.

Comment: I guess I shouldn't make a big deal about that. We all poured energy into it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
declare
  @period_start datetime ,
  @period_end   datetime

set @period_start = '2015-01-01 00:00:00.000'
set @period_end   = dateadd(month,1,@period_start)

select *
from foo
where foo.myDateTimeColumn >= @period_start
  and foo.myDateTimeColumn <  @period_end
```

Comment: Msg 139, Level 15, State 1, Line 0
Cannot assign a default value to a local variable.
Msg 139, Level 15, State 1, Line 0
Cannot assign a default value to a local variable.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 16
Must declare the scalar variable "@periods_start"

Comment: @gfuller40 Sounds like you are using SQL Server 2005, not SQL Server 2008 like your question is tagged.

Comment: oh crap you're right (9.0.5000) My bad.. I'm never on this server and all of our other ones are 2008.

Comment: See my amended answer. It should work for just about any version of Sql Server.

Comment: I'm receiving this error: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near '@period_start'.

Comment: sorry i fixed that error. I'm still getting "Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 13
Must declare the scalar variable "@period_start"."

Comment: Ok I got it to run and that WORKS!

Comment: Thank you very very much - this has been driving me absolutely NUTS!

Comment: Have you corrected the problems with the parens and or's. That's why you were getting most of the extra data back to 2008.

Comment: @shawnt00 is right. While the open-ended range is definitely a better approach to the date filter, the reason rows were coming back from outside of that range was because of improperly organized ORs and ANDs. I really doubt this query suddenly started returning the right data through changing *only* this part of the filter.

Comment: oh wow, you're right.... I didn't realize that could affect that so much. I guess it it seemed that was the only answer as I was tidying up the query awaiting responses.... Thanks guys...

Answer (score 0):

good way (will use indexes on postingdate column)

```
where lag.postingdate >= '20150101'
 and  lag.postingdate < '20150201'
```

easy but inefficient way (wont use any indexes even if there are on this datetime column)

```
where MONTH(lag.postingdate) = 1
and   YEAR(lag.postingdate) = 2015
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but neither example seems to work, I'm still getting all of the dates ranging from 2008. There are no time values with them, just the placeholders: 2008-01-24 00:00:00.000

Comment: @gfuller40 Post the query you have written.

Answer (score 0):

The true reason you were getting extra results going back to 2008 was because the query as written was including everything with posid = '1' regardless of the posting date.

You need to group your OR'd conditions with parentheses:

```
WHERE (pos.posid='1' OR pos.posid ='2') and prov.Laginclude ='y'
and MONTH(lag.postingdate) = 1 and YEAR(lag.postingdate) = 2015
```

If you use `pos.posid IN ('1', '2')` you can avoid the parens problem as well.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just skip all the casting?

AND lag.postingdate between '2015-01-01 00:00:00' and '2015-01-31 23:59:59'

Note the addition of the time to make the condition inclusive of the beginning and ending date - the beginning isn't important, but the ending would have missed everything on the 31st of Jan except the very first second.

Comment: Your query can still miss data. See https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx

Comment: I've tried this as well, still no go.. does it have something to do with the fact that it's a view?